# Uniformly Convergent Subsequence of a Pointwise Convergent Sequence of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I've come across a question in my Real Analysis course that I'm having quite a lot of difficulty finding an answer to. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685023/under-which-hypothesis-is-a-pointwise-convergent-sequence-of-functions-with-a-u) post has gotten me the closest to understanding the problem, which is as follows:

"Provide an example or explain why it is not possible: a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ that converges pointwise (but not uniformly) to a function $f$, with a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f$."

In general, what conditions need to be satisfied in order for a sequence of functions to have a uniformly convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 0):

Consider :
$$
f_{n}(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^{n}+1}
$$
Note that $(f_{n}(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f$ point-wise where :
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,& \text{if $x \in[0,1)$} \\
\frac{1}{2}, &\text{if $x=1$} \\
1,& \text{if $x \in(1,2]$} 
\end{cases}
$$
Each sequence of $f_{n}$ is continuous but the limit function is not continuous. Moreover, we know that if $f_{n}$ is continuous and uniform convergent, then it would imply continuity so if we take the contrapositive statement we can see that no subsequence of $f_{n}$ can converge uniformly to $f$ due to Arzelà–Ascoli theorem

Comment: Can you please clarify that last sentence? Specifically, why can't any subsequence of $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$?

Comment: If you have a sequence of function $f_{n}(x)$ and a set $E$ such that $f_{n}(x) : E\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $E$ **and** $f_{n}$ is uniformly convergent, then we can conclude that $f$ is **continuous** in $E$, well here we showed by an example that $f$ is not continuous in $E$ so by taking the contrapositive of this statement you can see that there can not exist any subsequence that could uniformly converge to $f$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused. I understand the Continuous Limit Thm, which says uniform convergence and continuity of $(f_n)$ implies continuity of $f$. How does knowing that $f$ is not continuous allow us to make a statement about the convergence of subsequences of $f_n$, when subsequences aren't mentioned in the theorem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what I showed is that we know a theorem $p\implies q$, then we used $\neg q \implies \neg p$ where $\neg q$ means $f_{n}$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: But the problem isn't about whether or not $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent. We suppose that $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent and need to answer a question about subsequences of $(f_n)$

Comment: My conclusion is based on Arzelà–Ascoli theorem since $f_{n}$ converges uniformly if and only if $f_{n_{k}}$ converges uniformly, its and if and only if statement so with $f_{n}$ just proven to not converge uniformly then there can't be any subsequence that could converge uniformly.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately my course is not covering the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, so I cannot use it in a solution. Do you know how else this problem can be answered?

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli theorem can be proven using Cantor's diagonalization argument otherwise I am unaware of another approach :/

Comment: Again, my course is not covering Cantor's diagonalization. I appreciate your answer though, and thank you for continuing to comment (even if my questions were dumb!)